# Sum of two functions taking integer values infinitely often

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $x \in Z^+$ and $n \in Z^+$. Let $f(x)$ be a function that takes integer values infinitely often. Then it follows that $f(x+n)$ also takes integer values infinitely often. Let $f(x)$ be continuous and differentiable. I think that if $p(x)=f(x)+f(x+n)$ takes integer values more than once than it takes integer values infinitely often.

Is this a known property? Can anybody give a counter example to this?

Edit: $f(x)$ is not a piece-wise function. I am extremely sorry that I didn't mention these things before. I have been thinking about this all day and I didn't realize that I had assumed these.

Comment: Please quantify your variables: what type of number is $c$ and at what type of numbers $x$ are you interested in integer values of $f(x)$?

Comment: @KCd both $x$ and $c$ are positive integers.

Answer (score 2):

Try $f(n)=\log_2(n)$, and various values of $c$.

Comment: Good example...I found another example similar to this one, $p(x)$ takes integer value only once. If I may consider $p(x)$ taking integer value only once as peculiarity..can you give me another example such that $p(x)$ takes integer values more than once but not infinitely often?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(x) = 0$ at infinitely many integer values $x = n_1, n_2, \ldots$, and $f(x) = \pi$ otherwise. Then $f(x) + f(x + 1)$ is an integer iff $x$ and $x + 1$ are both in the set
$\lbrace n_1, n_2, \ldots\rbrace$. By choosing the $n_i$ suitably, you can make this happen for as many $x$ as you like.

Comment: @Micheal Behrend Sorry, I failed to mention that I am working with continuous functions.

Comment: @Idiot7 please *update* your question to fix the ambiguities you left out: what type of numbers you evaluate the function at and that you want a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think the idea can be modified. Let $f(x) = 0$ at certain integer values $n_1, n_2, \ldots$ as before. Let $f(x) = 1/3$ away from these values, but make $f(x)$ continuous by having narrow spikes going down to the points where $f(x) = 0$. Then the same argument will still work.

Comment: It would make the function un-differentiable then doesn't it? Can you give me an example when $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable.

Comment: You could round the corners of the spikes.

Comment: I am extremely sorry. I have been thinking about this assuming something and I didn't specify about this in the question. $f(x)$ is not a piece-wise function. I apologise again.

Answer (score 0):

I found an example such that what I considered was wrong. Infinite product formula like this one $f(x) = (x-1) \prod_{p \in P} (1 - \frac{e^x}{e^p})^2$ is equal to 0 when $x$ is prime or $x=1$.